TOTP code doesn't generate the same code as in the google authenticator app
I'm trying to automate the flow of login onto a panel and everything works fine until the OTP code is generated. For some reason the OTP generated doesn't match the code on the google auth app.
I'm using gherkin and typescript to write tests, and otplib for OTP code generating.
I have an OTPHelper file where the setup is located and what I'm calling into the step definition file for OTP input for automation.
import { authenticator } from 'otplib'
import { createHmac } from 'crypto'
import { globalPanelType } from '../step_definitions/panel'
import * as string_decoder from 'node:string_decoder'

export let base32Secret
export class TOTPHelper {
  private readonly secretKey: string

  constructor(secretKey: string) {
    this.secretKey = secretKey
    this.configureAuthenticator()
  }

  private configureAuthenticator(): void {
    authenticator.options = {
      createHmac: createHmac,
      digits: 6,
      period: 30,
      step: 30,
      window: [1, 1],
    }
  }
  
  generateTOTPCode(): string {
    try {
      this.configureAuthenticator()

      return authenticator.generate(this.secretKey)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error generating TOTP code:', error)
      throw new Error('Failed to generate TOTP code')
    }
  }
  

  verifyTOTPCode(code: string): boolean {
    try {
      this.configureAuthenticator()

      if (!code || typeof code !== 'string') {
        console.error('Invalid code provided for verification')
        return false
      }
      return authenticator.verify({
        token: code,
        secret: this.secretKey,
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error verifying TOTP code:', error)
      return false
    }
  }
}

export function getTOTPCode(): string {
  console.log('Debug - Global Panel Type:', globalPanelType)
  console.log('Debug - Process Env:', {
    MERCHANT_SECRET_KEY: process.env.MERCHANT_SECRET_KEY ? 'SET' : 'UNDEFINED',
    ADMIN_SECRET_KEY: process.env.ADMIN_SECRET_KEY ? 'SET' : 'UNDEFINED',
  })
  let base32Secret: string | undefined
  switch (globalPanelType) {
    case 'merchant':
      base32Secret = process.env.MERCHANT_SECRET_KEY
      break
    case 'admin':
      base32Secret = process.env.ADMIN_SECRET_KEY
      break
    default:
      throw new Error(`Panel type unknown: ${globalPanelType}`)
  }

  if (!base32Secret) {
    console.error('Environment variables: ', {
      MERCHANT_SECRET_KEY: process.env.MERCHANT_SECRET_KEY,
      ADMIN_SECRET_KEY: process.env.ADMIN_SECRET_KEY,
      globalPanelType: globalPanelType,
    })
    throw new Error(`No secret key found for panely type: ${globalPanelType}`)
  }
  console.log('Debug Base32 Secret:', base32Secret)
  const totpHelper = new TOTPHelper(base32Secret)
  return totpHelper.generateTOTPCode()
}

otp.ts step definition file
import { When } from './util'
import { TOTPHelper, getTOTPCode } from '../helpers/OtpHelper'

const { I } = inject()

When(/^I enter OTP code$/, async function () {
  const base32Secret = getTOTPCode()
  const currentTotpHelper = new TOTPHelper(base32Secret)
  const token = currentTotpHelper.generateTOTPCode()
  const isValid = currentTotpHelper.verifyTOTPCode(token)

  if (!isValid) {
    throw new Error('Generated token is invalid')
  }
  await I.waitForText('OTP', 5)
  console.log('Entering OTP...', token)
  await I.fillField('OTP Code', token)
})


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
